# ExceptionFilterAttribute not handling properties exceptions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I implemented an ExceptionFilterAttribute class and registered it in the WebApiConfig class.
The action filter works good and handles any exception happened in any action but the problem is: when an exception happens while in any of the controller properties the action filter not handle this exception

```
[NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute]
public class AnyController : APIController
{
    private readonly ModelDBContext _db = new ModelDBContext();

    //some actions
}
```

in the mentioned example, the constructor of ModelDBContext contains some logic which may cause exception. This exception will not be handled by the ExceptionFilterAttribute. Why??? And how to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is scope.

When the controller is instanced the *private class member* `_db` will initialize before any class methods execute. This is a CLR behavior.

Thus, an action filter will not catch an exception incurred during construction/initialization of your controller object, such as a failure to construct a `ModelDBContext` instance.

One solution is to create and dispose of `ModelDBContext` instances on every request, and some may argue this is the proper approach if you intend to gracefully handle (or log) connectivity failures (whether it's to a DB or a back-end service.)

You may also find `IServiceLocator` and a framework such as 'Unity' or 'Ninject' useful so that you're not "hardcoding" `new ModelDBContext();` statements everywhere, but that's another subject. The root cause is you're initializing outside of the scope of an action method, action filters won't catch it.

Answer (score 1):

basically, simple answer is simple: exception filter is action-level filter.

Check this diagram first: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/05/06/asp-net-mvc4-web-api-stack-diagram-currently-in-development.aspx
Then navigate to [ApiController](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs), line #232. There you can see that if there is at least one filter then [ExceptionFilterResult](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/ExceptionFilterResult.cs) will be used to wrap end action result. 
Inside ExceptionFilterResult there is simple try-catch, if exception is thrown then all registered exception filters are called.
So, short summary of everything written above:
1) exception filter is not responsible for handling errors above controller's action
2) exception filter does not exist at the moment when controller's instance is created by DI container and when your ModelDBContext throws an exception

I hope this answers your question.